# I am trying to handel an error , it goes in the while loop only twice and then coming out of it, can anybody tell me why ? Many Thanks

Tags: python, selenium, while-loop

Below is my code, I am working on one application error here and I want my while loop to run untill the error is gone and it accepts the value

```
  def Handle_ErrorToHigh():
    val = "2500"
    actual_val = int(val)
    const_val = 100
    new_loan.send_keys(val)
    post = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Post')]")))
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", post)
    #post.click()
    i = 0
    while len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Close']")) > 0:
        try:
            if(len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Close']"))) > 0:
                print("Alert is visible" , i)
                i  = i + 1
                print(i)
                close_btn=wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Close')]")))
                webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(close_btn).click(close_btn).perform()
                new_loan.clear()
                time.sleep(1)
                keys_to_send = actual_val - const_val
                time.sleep(1)
                new_loan.send_keys(str(keys_to_send))
                time.sleep(1)
                wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[contains(text(),'Post')]"))).click()
                #driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", post_btn)
                const_val = const_val  + 10
                if const_val >= 1000:
                    break
                else:
                    print('Post must have worked')
                    break
        except:
            print('Something went wrong in code')
            break

Error_length = []
Error_length = len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Close']"))
if Error_length > 0:
    Handle_ErrorToHigh()
else:
    print("I did not go to IF")

print ("Error lenth:", Error_length)
```

My issue is : while loop is working only twice and then its coming out of loop and printing "I did not go to IF" Can anybody suggest anything here ?

Note: Close is the button on the error

Comment: if you hit `print("I did not go to IF")`  then it's not entered the loop. Python won't run an `IF` and an `ELSE` - that wouldn't make sense. You'll want to look elsewhere in your script to verify your logic.

Comment: Additionally `break` completely exits the loop. You have `if const_val >= 1000:                    break  else:  print('Post must have worked')  break`   -- BOTH OF THESE HAVE A `BREAK`. When it hits this point it will exit the while loop. Did you mean `continue` which will restart the loop?

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your replay, Actually earlier I had While True condition, hence had those break.  Do you mean I should not have them ?